# Accelerometer IC single/double click event

Tags: integrated-circuit, accelerometer

What are Accelerometer single and double click event, can someone clarify it for me with some theory and/or practice?

Comment: The following might help http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00196199.pdf - it's just pretty much for detecting finger taps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accelerometer single and double click events are easiest to understand if one considers them as a **tap** and **double-tap** equivalent of what we do with our computer mouse buttons.

The accelerometer MEMS devices that support the feature, incorporate the intelligence to determine when a tap is sensed, or two taps in rapid succession within a set period. The logic also distinguishes between such taps, and vibration due to, for instance, a car's movement. Click / double-click detection also filters out the sharp impact from a device being dropped, for instance, and will not generate a false positive "click" event if this occurs.

Once such a tap or double-tap event is detected, the accelerometer notifies the host microcontroller of this using either an interrupt line, or normal digital query-response. This saves the programmer from writing reams of code to identify, for instance,

- "*a pair of brief accelerations in opposing vectors in rapid succession*" i.e. a **click**,
- "*two pairs of brief opposing accelerations, with more than `x` delay between the pairs, and less than `y` delay between the pairs*" i.e. a **double-click**, and
- "*way too many brief accelerations in sequence, so it can't be someone tapping the device twice*", i.e. a **false alarm**.

This click / double-click detection permits a **hand-held device to be used like a single-button computer mouse**, as an input interface, with the mouse button clicking being replaced by tapping on the device.